# Incompatible block pointer type? Cannot return NSArray

Tags: objective-c, nsarray, objective-c-blocks

I have a block we return an array in callback. Then I create another method to store that array as below:

```
- (NSArray *)getUserData{

[self fetchDataByUserId:self.userID completionHandler:^(NSArray *record) {
    return record;
}];
}
```

I received this kind of error so please help me, I don't understand.

"Incompatible block pointer types sending 'NSArray *(^)(NSArray * __strong) to parameter of type 'void (^)(NSArray *_strong)"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reason is explained by @user3386109, this is the right way.

```
- (void)getUserData:(void (^)(NSArray *record))complete {

    [self fetchDataByUserId:self.userID completionHandler:^(NSArray *record) {
        complete(record);
    }];

}
```

or

```
- (void)getUserData:(void (^)(NSArray *record))complete {

    [self fetchDataByUserId:self.userID completionHandler:complete];

}
```

Moreover, about the Error Message: "Incompatible block pointer type", you should google "How to use Block in objective-c", ex: http://rypress.com/tutorials/objective-c/blocks

Because your `completionHanler` is not a `return type block`, it's a `void` block.

`(void (^)(NSArray *record))`
is different with
`(NSArray * (^)(NSArray *record))`

Comment: Thank you for you explanation, it's very details. But what should I do to have a method which received data from this fetch. Some kind as: -(NSArray *)userDataLoaded;

Comment: Only if your fetchData method can return NSArray, instead of Block. Ex: NSArray *record = [self fetchDataByUserId]; return record;

Answer (score 1):

The `completionHandler` is not called immediately, and is not expected to return a value. You can think of the code in the `completionHandler` as a callback function. The caller is some framework code that executes whenever the `fetch` completes. The framework code calls your `completionHandler` to let you know that the `fetch` is finished, and doesn't expect any return value.

So the `getUserData` method should really be a `startUserDataFetch` method, and you need additional code to process the data if ever / whenever it actually arrives.

Comment: Thank you so much, I actually understand more about block by your answer. Whenever I have enough point, I will vote for you :)